# how to know the current running version of VestaCP?

Tags: vesta

I have VestaCP Installed on My Linux VPS and I want to know what is the version of the current VestaCP that is running on my server. How I do this?

Answer (score 1):

create a new bash file anywhere you want , for example /root/ with the name check_vesta_version.sh and add the following code to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#vestapc version checker
#beta script

# Checking installed vesta version
if [ -d "/etc/sysconfig" ]; then
    rpm_format="VERSION='%{VERSION}'"
    rpm_format="$rpm_format RELEASE='%{RELEASE}'"
    rpm_format="$rpm_format ARCH='%{ARCH}'"
    rpm_format="$rpm_format UTIME='%{INSTALLTIME}'\n"
    eval $(rpm --queryformat="$rpm_format" -q vesta)
    DATE=$(date -d @$UTIME +%F)
    TIME=$(date -d @$UTIME +%T)
else
    dpkg_data=$(dpkg-query -s vesta)
    pkg_date=$(stat -c "%Y" /var/lib/dpkg/info/vesta.list)
    ARCH=$(echo "$dpkg_data"|grep Architecture |cut -f 2 -d ' ')
    VERSION=$(echo "$dpkg_data"|grep ^Version |cut -f 2 -d ' '|cut -f 1 -d \-)
    RELEASE=$(echo "$dpkg_data"|grep ^Version |cut -f 2 -d ' '|cut -f 2 -d \-)
    DATE=$(date -d @$pkg_date +"%F")
    TIME=$(date -d @$pkg_date +"%T")
fi

echo $VERSION-$RELEASE
```

and then run the file using

```
bash check_vesta_version.sh
```

and you will get your current running vesta cp version , for example: 0.9.8-22

if you want to chek vestacp website to know what is the latest avialable version to download of vestacp run the following command in your shell command

```
wget -q -T 1 -t 1 http://c.vestacp.com/latest.txt -O -
```

Also you can know if there is an update of your vestacp version by running the following command

```
v-list-sys-vesta-updates
```

or

```
/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-list-sys-vesta-updates
```